# Windows Command Prompt hangs after running batch file

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line, command-prompt

I'm trying to setup a quick batch file where it sets up my development environment when run (on Windows 10). So far, all I'm doing is:

```
@echo off

w:
pushd directory_of_project

call build.bat //build project
call vsdbg.bat //run a batch file which opens up visual studio's debugger
call 4ed //Open my code editor exe

popd
```

Everything works fine, except after everything has been setup my command window hangs and I can't Ctrl+C out of it. The command prompt only finishes after closing the 4ed program. Is there a way to modify my batch file to prevent this from happening so I don't have to open up another command prompt window?

Comment: The command processor waits for each command or program to finish. `4ed` is actually called `4ed.exe`, right? so you don't need `call`. To not wait for its termination, use `start`, like this: `start "" 4ed.exe`, or `start "" /B 4ed.exe` for `4ed` to use the same console window...

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
@echo off

w:
pushd directory_of_project

call build.bat //build project
call vsdbg.bat //run a batch file which opens up visual studio's debugger
start 4ed //Open my code editor exe

popd
```